# VB6 Mouse events and interaction with Lines

Tags: vb6

I am making an equation grapher in VB6, and I have constructed a piece of code that displays the coordinates of the mousepointer when it is on a picturebox (the picturebox being the place where the curve is displayed).

I have successfully managed to do this, and the co-ordinates of the mouse display fine, until the mouse is placed onto the axis (constructed by the line function). The co-ords displayed when the pointer is on the axis are obviously wrong.

When the mouse pointer is on the y-axis, the x-value, instead of being 0, is some random number. 
When the mouse pointer is on the x-axis, the y-value instead of being 0, is some random number.

The co-ordinates are being displayed on a status bar. Below is the code that may help you help me solve this problem.

Below is the code for the co-ords being displayed on the statusbar:

```
Private Sub picGraph_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
StatusBar1.Panels(1).Text = "x: " & X & " - y: " & Y

End Sub
```

Below is the code for the construction of the axis:

```
Public Sub Form_Activate()

Dim xmin As Single
Dim xmax As Single
Dim Dx As Single
Dim ymin As Single
Dim ymax As Single
Dim i As Integer


'set default bounds and Dx

xmin = -10
xmax = 10
ymin = -10
ymax = 10
Dx = 0.1

'scale graph to default bounds

picGraph.Scale (xmin, ymax)-(xmax, ymin)

'draw graph axis

picGraph.Cls
picGraph.Line (xmin, 0)-(xmax, 0), vbRed
picGraph.Line (0, ymin)-(0, ymax), vbRed

For i = 0 To xmin Step -1
    picGraph.Line (i, -0.25)-Step(0, 0.5), vbBlue
Next i
For i = 0 To xmax
    picGraph.Line (i, -0.25)-Step(0, 0.5), vbBlue
Next i
For i = 0 To ymin Step -1
    picGraph.Line (-0.25, i)-Step(0.5, 0), vbBlue
Next i
For i = 0 To ymax
        picGraph.Line (-0.25, i)-Step(0.5, 0), vbBlue
Next i

End Sub
```

BTW: When the mouse pointer is on the curve being graphed, there is no problem with the mouse co-ords.

Any insight into why the mouse co-ords get messed up when on the axis would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number that is showing you is written in engineering notation.  So rather than showing you 0.002 it is showing it as 2E-3.
If you change the StatusBar1.Panels(1).Text = "x: " & X & " - y: " & Y to have a format in it you might find it is closer to what you need.  So it would be something like

```
StatusBar1.Panels(1).Text = "x: " & format$(X,"0.00") & " - y: " & format$(Y,"0.00")
```